# mongodb RESTfull api in python using fastapi and mongoengine

Tags: python, api, rest, mongodb

So I wrote a a RESTfull api for a mongodb with **python3.7**, **fastapi** and **mongoengine** and id love to get feedback on how I should make my code more readable, clean, and dry.

basically there are 4 main routes :

1. Route to get all objects from a collection.
2. Route to get one object from a  collection by a specific identifier (doc_id).
3. Route to post a new object to a collection.
4. Route to update an object from the db by a specific identifier (doc_id).

```
#db_api.py
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Dict
from mongoengine import connect,disconnect
from mongoengine import errors
from schemas import *
import os

MONGODB_ADDR = os.environ.get("MONGODB_ADDR", "chaos.mongodb.openshift")
MONGODB_PORT = os.environ.get("MONGODB_PORT", 8080)
DB_NAME = os.environ.get("DB_NAME", "chaos")
LISTEN_PORT = int(os.environ.get("LISTEN_PORT", 5001))

app = FastAPI()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def create_db_client():
    try:
        ## Add authentication
        connect(db=DB_NAME, host=MONGODB_ADDR, port=MONGODB_PORT)
    except errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
        print("error connecting to mongodb")

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_db_client():
    pass

@app.get("/{collection}")
def read_object(collection: Collections):
    # Get all documents from collection
    collection_object = get_collection_object(collection)
    output = [document.to_dict() for document in collection_object.objects]
    return output

@app.get("/{collection}/{doc_id}")
def read_one_object(collection: Collections,doc_id: str):
    try:
        # Get specific document from collection depending on route
        # try to get first document, considering there could not be more then 1
        collection_object = get_collection_object(collection)
        doc_identifier_to_doc_id = {collection_object.get_identifier() : doc_id}
        # Get all objects that have the doc_id and
        # return the first one as a dict
        output = collection_object.objects(**doc_identifier_to_doc_id)[0].to_dict()
    except (IndentationError, IndexError):
        output = f"No such document '{doc_id}' in '{collection}' collection"
    return output

@app.post("/{collection}/{doc_id}")
def write_object(collection: Collections, document: Dict = {}):
    try:
        collection = get_collection_object(collection)
        document = collection(**document)
        document.save()
        return document.to_dict()
    except TypeError as E:
        print(E)
        return 'missing parameters'
    except (errors.FieldDoesNotExist , errors.ValidationError):
        return 'unknown parameter '

@app.put("/{collection}/{doc_id}")
def update_object(collection: Collections, doc_id : str, document: Dict = {}):
    try:
        collection_object = get_collection_object(collection)
        doc_identifier_to_doc_id = {collection_object.get_identifier() : doc_id}
        document_object = collection_object.objects(**doc_identifier_to_doc_id)[0]
        document_object.update(**document)
        document_object.save()
        document_object = collection_object.objects(**doc_identifier_to_doc_id)[0]
        return document_object.to_dict()
    except TypeError:
        return 'missing parameters'
    except (errors.FieldDoesNotExist , errors.ValidationError):
        return 'unknown parameter '

def get_collection_object(collection):
    if collection == Collections.servers:
        document = Server
    elif collection == Collections.groups:
        document = Group
    elif collection == Collections.logs:
        document = Log
    return document
```

Ive created schemas for the collections I have in my db (ive already dicided to create a parent abstract class for all my documents that specifies the to_dict function and other stuff all of them need).

```
#schemas.py
from mongoengine import *
from enum import Enum

class Collections(str, Enum):
    servers = "servers"
    groups = "groups"
    logs = "logs"


class Log(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'logs'}
    name = StringField()
    logs = DictField()
    successful = BooleanField(default=False)
    date = StringField()
    victim = StringField()
    owner = StringField(required=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_identifier():
        return 'name'

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "name": self.name,
            "logs": self.logs,
            "successful": self.successful,
            "date" : self.date,
            "victim" : self.victim,
            "owner": self.owner
        }


class Server(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'servers'}
    dns = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    active = BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = ListField(StringField(),default=[])
    os_type = StringField(required=True)
    last_fault = StringField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_identifier():
        return 'dns'

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "dns": self.dns,
            "active": self.active,
            "groups": self.groups,
            "os_type": self.os_type,
            "last_fault": self.last_fault
        }

class Group(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'groups'}
    name = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    active = BooleanField(default=False)
    last_fault = StringField()
    owner = StringField(required=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_identifier():
        return 'name'

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "name": self.name,
            "active": self.active,
            "last_fault": self.last_fault,
            "owner" : self.owner
        }
```